# Strange 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined' error when array is already defined typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a strange error when trying to push some strings to an array.

This might be a duplicate but I have found no answer in 50 threads..

`Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public messageList = [];

receive = function(msg) {
  if (msg.length > 0) {
    this.messageList.push(msg);
  }
}
```

`receive`is a callback from socket.io.

.. where `msg` is a string.

I also tried `public messageList: Array<string> = [];` without success..

What can I do?

EDIT: as someone pointed it out, the method is a callback from socket.io

Comment: `public messageList : string[]  = [];` also use  `if (msg && msg.length > 0)`

Comment: thanks Joel, but it still won't work and I get the same error..

Comment: @Martin Can you please share the method which has your `if` statement and how are you calling that method. It appears that it is an issue of `this` scope. Please share the method and how are you calling it.

Comment: try console `this.messageList`  before pushing message and post the answer here

Comment: @user2216584 I edited the question, you're right!

Comment: @JoelJoseph yep you found it too: undefined..

Comment: Read about arrow functions.

Comment: You should use an arrow function: `receive = msg => {` and drop the `function` keyword. Otherwise, does what @MrCode. advises

Comment: @CristianTraìna It works! Thank you very much, I will read your link thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

declare this as self then use self in callback function

e.g

```
 let self = this;
 public messageList = [];

 receive = function(msg) {
   if (msg.length > 0) {
     self.messageList.push(msg);
  }
 }
```

Comment: This is an old way, have it like: `receive = (msg) =>  {
   if (msg.length > 0) {
     this.messageList.push(msg);
  }`, this will preserve the `this` reference lexically.

Comment: @xyz agree. but as per is requirement I have suggested.

Comment: I also don't advise to use `_this` in TypeScript, since this is a reserved keyword inside the transpilers (to transpil `this` inside arrow functions). Using `self` would be better

Comment: @xyz this made it work perfectly, I need to get into the documentation, Angular is heavy man! Thanks for your help

Comment: @CristianTraìna thanks will modify the ans.

Comment: @Martin This is not angular, this is JavaScript.

Comment: I am learning both at the same time